# Stuck on a part in a java project

Tags: java

"If a player's playerID ends in 00 to 49, this person is on the “lucky list”; however if the playID ends in 50 to 99, this person is on the “normal list”."

```
    //Players ID, is what i have so far
    System.out.println("Please enter the player’s ID (8 digits): ");
    int playerId = input.nextInt();

   //When i use if else statements i can select for certain cases. for example
   if (playerId % 50)
       normalList;
   if (playerId % 3)
       luckyList;
```

These are two example that i can think of. I assume there is a shorter and more logical way to do this but i dont have a clue how.

Comment: "nothing has worked for me" show what you've tried.

Comment: If you don't show your best attempt, how will we know what you may be doing wrong and how to help you? Please fix this question, and voting to close it until you do.

Comment: `I used the scanner tool to allow for player ID to be input` -- share your code and then it will be easier to guide you

Comment: //Players ID
  System.out.println("Please enter the player’s ID (8 digits): ");
  int playerId = input.nextInt();

Comment: Please edit your question, show your code there, and put just a little more effort into it.

Comment: if get stuck on the next part. how i would write: if (playerId % 2) for example but i dont understand who to specifically look at the last two digits.

Comment: Perhaps you need a little bit of google (show some efforts) to do what is needed after getting the player id

Comment: So now you have shared the code. Have you run it? What is the issue you are facing exactly?

Comment: the first part of the code works fine. the objective is to have someone input an 8-digit number, then based on the last two digits of that number they will be put into two lists. list 1 - everyone two the last two digits 00-49 and list two everyone with the last two digits 50-99. this is where im stuck.

Comment: where are you checking if the input is indeed a number and that too of 8 digits?

Comment: The input must be an 8-digit number. The last two digits are important because they determine which list a user is put on. These are the rules of the project.

Comment: Yes the input must be an 8-digit number. So where is you code checking that to ensure the user doesn't enter anything else.

Comment: is there a way to do this using basic math operations (add subtract multiplication division and mod) in java.

Answer (score -1):

Be more clear on what `normal list;` and what `luckyList;` are. You say lists, so I am assuming you are using `array` or `java.util.ArrayList` to store your objects.

What I would do is to the effect of this:

```
  `//Players ID, is what you have so far.

    int playerID;
        System.out.println("Please enter the player’s ID (8 digits): ");
        playerID=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please re-enter the player's ID(8 digits):");
        String IDword=input.next(); //can also use nextLine here


     //now what happens is I have made a string version and an int version of your ID. Now, using charAt, I can access the last two values.

       if(IDword.charAt(IDword.length()-2)=='4')
{
LuckyList.add(playerID);
}
      if(IDword.charAt(IDword.length()-2)=='3')
{
LuckyList.add(playerID);
}
      if(IDword.charAt(IDword.length()-2)=='2')
{
LuckyList.add(playerID);
}
      if(IDword.charAt(IDword.length()-2)=='1')
{
LuckyList.add(playerID);
}
      if(IDword.charAt(IDword.length()-2)=='0')
{
LuckyList.add(playerID);
}
       else 
           normalList.add(playerID);`
```

This detects the second to last digit- if it is 4 or less, it adds to luckyList.  Else, it will add to normalList.

You may just want to add something indicating that the data is always 8 digits (that just being `if(IDword.size()==8)` do the following.

Comment: You're comparing a `char` to a `String` and you don't need to make all those individual comparisons to determine which list it should go in and your code needs to be formatted better.